# jQuery not working on Bootstrap 3 Modal dom elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

**my goal:**

I have a modal that I want to use to add job positions to the db.I choose the `starting date`, and check the `still-here` check box  it is supposed to hide the`ending date` fields and show a div in its place saying `I currently work here`.

**My problem:**

Is that my jQuery doesn't pick up the dom elements on the modal... I have `console.log()` on the check box to see if is checked or not, but it doesn't work that well. it only gives the initial value of when the modal is launched and not the values of every time I select/ deselect the check box.

see my code example [here](http://bootply.com/102989)

**My question:**

what am I missing, why is it not working and how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: the function checks on modal load only it does not check on change so write on chnage function for the checkbox

Comment: I recommend checking the check box state with $('#checkboxId').prop('checked')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $(".current-position").hide();
        console.log($('#still_here').is(':checked'));

        });

    });

$('#still_here').on('change',function(){
      if($('#myModal .modal-body #still_here').prop('checked')){
            $("#myModal .modal-body .current-position").show();
            console.log($("#myModal .modal-body #to_month"));
            $("#myModal .modal-body #to_month").hide();
            $("#myModal .modal-body #to_year").hide();          
        }else{
            $("#myModal .modal-body .current-position").hide();
            $("#myModal .modal-body #to_month").show();
            $("#myModal .modal-body #to_year").show();
        }
});
```